# Command with 2 paths when running a docker container

Tags: docker

Hey I'm very new at this so bear with me please.

I'm trying to run a docker container I exported. The container was running with command:
[image]

I've tried using this:

`sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=test testcontainer --entrypoint=/sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh`

However I get errors:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--entrypoint=/sbin/tini\": stat --entrypoint--/sbin/tini: no such file or directory": unknown.`

I've also tried a combination of them with a space between them like such:

`sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=test testcontainer --entrypoint=/sbin/tini /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh`

How would i go about to running that command?

Comment: Normally metadata like that would be baked into the image.  Can you add the Dockerfile you used to build the image to the question?

Comment: it was an import of an existing jenkins container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--entrypoint` would go before the image name

`sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=test --entrypoint=/sbin/tini testcontainer /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh`

The extra arguments would follow that to become the command (and dashes aren't needed.

Or if bash is the default entrypoint, you can give the whole thing as a command.

`sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=test testcontainer bash -c "/sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"`

Comment: Hmm so I tried the last one, and it says `touch: cannot touch '': No such file or directory` also `Can not write to . Wrong volume permissions?`

Comment: That seems like an error internal to the Jenkins script, not an issue with the entrypoint

Comment: i'm marking this an the answer cause it worked, thank you